# Metaball morphing into another object

Tags: shape-keys

I’m creating an animation with metaballs using animation nodes. The idea is to have the metaballs interact with each other for some time, then one of the metaballs morphs into an object.

I know about shape keys and have tried to do 2 renders: one with just the metaballs, one with a regular sphere with the size of the metaball shaping to the object and to compose these two renders together, but this is a lot of post-processing work without amazing results and I’m wondering if there would be any other way to morph a specific (or any) metaball to a complete new object with the same metaball-stretch-like morph?